# How to catch the exception thrown from a lambda

Tags: java, android, java-8

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but how do I catch the `IOException` that I rethrow from the lambda?

```
   Future<Response<R>> futureResp = pool.submit(() -> {
        Response<R> res;
        try {
            res = call.execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
        return res;
    });
```

The entire method would look like this:

```
@Override
public RetrofitResponse<R> adapt(Call<R> call) {
    if (networkUtil.isOnline( ctx )) {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        Future<Response<R>> futureResp = pool.submit(() -> {
            Response<R> res;
            try {
                res = call.execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
            return res;
        });

        Response<R> resp;
        try {
            resp = futureResp.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new RetrofitResponse<>( ErrorStatus.PROCESSING_ERROR, e.getMessage() );
        }
        if (resp != null) {
            return new RetrofitResponse<>( new ApiResponse<>(resp) );
        } else {
            return new RetrofitResponse<>( ErrorStatus.PROCESSING_ERROR, "Response is null" );
        }
    } else {
        return new RetrofitResponse<>( ErrorStatus.NETWORK_ERROR, "No internet network detected!" );
    }

}
```

I basically want to wrap errors in a custom object that keeps state about possible errors that are not necessarily related to either lack of network connection or http errors.

Warpping this block in another try-catch block doesn't work since the ide indicates that there is no IOException to be caught.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with lambda expressions at all. Therefore, you don't need to catch and re-throw the exception “from the lambda”; you can simply submit your job like

```
Future<Response<R>> futureResp = pool.submit(() -> call.execute());
```

The key point is that this will invoke `submit(Callable)` and the `Callable` interface allows throwing checked exceptions. And [`Future.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--) states:

> #### Throws:
>
> …
> ExecutionException - if the computation threw an exception

So when you `catch(ExecutionException)` at the `get()` call, its [cause](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause--) will be the thrown `IOException`, if any.

Comment: Aah I get it, now this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the original `Exception` and throw it as `UncheckedException` maybe as your own that extends beforementioned and holds the original exception as its cause.

Then catch this `UncheckedException` and if needed dig the cause from it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rethrown your error as a UncheckedException

```
  catch(IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
```

Or extend RuntimeException and throw a custom one.

You will get the error in the future.get()

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I will get the error in future.get(), that clarifies how I should handle it